# SUM en php y sql server

Tags: php, sql-server

Hola Buen día les explico mi problema es el siguiente tengo una base de datos en la cual deseo que la tabla hoja_costos en la columna total se sume todas las cantidades y despues se multiplique por 1*16 de acuerdo si tienen el mimo folio_hoja e imprimirlo en php.

//Esta es la tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

//Este es el codigo para que aparezca en php

```
 <table id="hoja" class="table" >
    <thead >
      <tr id="heads">
        <th class="col-md-3" ></th>
        <th class="col-md-5"></th>
        <th class="col-md-5"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr>

    <td >   
    <a class=" btn btn-md btn-info"  href="#cost" data-toggle="modal"><center> Nueva Hoja de Costo </center></a>

</td>
<?php
    
    include '../includes/db.php';
    $folio_hoja=$_GET['folio_hoja'];

      $query=  mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SUM(hoja_costos.importe_total)*1.16 as sumtotal FROM hoja_costos where folio_hoja='$folio_hoja'");         
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        
    ?>
<td >   
<center> <div >
<h5><label class="control-label">IVA:</label>
        <FONT COLOR="TEAL">16% </FONT><br>
        <label class="control-label">Total:</label>
        <input type ="text" value ="<?php echo $row['sumtotal']?>"readonly>
        <FONT COLOR="TEAL">  </FONT></h5>  
    </div> </center> 
</td>
```

//por ultimo este es el error que me sale cuando se imprime

**Warning**:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in **C:\xampp\htdocs\KYO SYSTEM\sistema_ventas\detalle_hoja.php** on line **223**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Quisiera saber si me podrian decir en que estoy mal por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu while no tiene la estructura que debe, no tiene las llaves, no se sabe que es lo que abarca.

Prueba con

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
   $total = $row['sumtotal'];
}

<input type ="text" value ="<?php echo $total; ?>"readonly>
```

Nunca olvides el **;** de las instrucciones, eso te va a generar problemas.

Lo hice sin corroborar la estructura del código y asumiendo que tu query funciona en tu DBM.

Comment: me ayudo mucho tu respuesta muchas muchas gracias ya me permitio lo que buscaba